# @client.on(events.NewMessage not working :(

Tags: telegram, telethon

im trying to code a bot who spams a message on another bot, i tried reading the docs but it just won't work :/ this is the message i get when i get paired with a user:

---

Sei stato inserito in chat con un utente!

DATI DELL'UTENTE

Scrivigli subito un messaggio

*button 1*

*button 2*

---

i need to respond to this text with a message i type in input and another one after a sec or two, but the code just stops and doesn't even respond.. here's the code:

```js
import asyncio 
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
from telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist import PeerFloodError
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerUser
import time

api_id = xxx
api_hash = 'xxx'
messaggio = input("inserisci messaggio: ")
comando = input("inserisci comando: ")
client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

time.sleep(5)


@client.on(events.NewMessage(from_users=<botname>, pattern=' Sei stato inserito in chat con un utente!.+'))
async def handler(event):
    await event.respond("messaggio")
    time.sleep(5)
    await event.respond("comando")
    time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues here.
First of all, using `time.sleep()` with `asyncio` is not reccomended. Then, the client is not running so you need to run it.

You can do something like this:

```
import asyncio 
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
from telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist import PeerFloodError
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerUser
import time

api_id = 123456
api_hash = "gwudshojia24153124321"
messaggio = input("inserisci messaggio: ")
comando = input("inserisci comando: ")
client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

@client.on(events.NewMessage(from_users=<bot_name>, pattern=' Sei stato inserito in chat con un utente!.+'))
async def handler(event):
    await event.respond(messaggio)
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await event.respond(comando)
    await asyncio.sleep(10)

client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: mhh okay, that fixes it, but still when i receive the message from the bot it doesn't reply to it the full message is:

 Sei stato inserito in chat con un utente!

 DATI DELL'UTENTE

 Scrivigli subito un messaggio

button 1

button 2

as i understood, pattern should see a message and reply to a message with the exact text and ".+" something else. any way to help me?

Comment: If you need to reply on that message, then replace `event.respond` with `event.reply`.

Comment: i meant, it doesn't type anything, maybe is there something wrong with the message i get?

Comment: If the bot is not handling that messages maybe there's something wrong with the pattern. I suggest you to check if the message starts with that pattern (see: https://regexone.com/lesson/line_beginning_end) so you're sure that the bot will handle that message.

Comment: that didn't helped much but i fixed it, thanks btw, 


i created an str named "messaggio_bot" and changed 

pattern=' Sei stato inserito in chat con un utente!.+'))

in

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats="<botname>", pattern=messaggio_bot))

Comment: Oh okay. If you've found the solution to your problem, you can answer your own question and mark it as answered or, you can mark my question if I've helped you.